# Chose a function with apply() based on some condition

Tags: r, apply

In `apply()` function, I need to provide a function name. But in my case, that function name needs to be based on some other condition. Below is such example:

```
library(dplyr)
Function = TRUE
as.data.frame(matrix(1:12, 4)) %>%
    mutate(Res = apply(as.matrix(.), 1, ifelse(Function, ~mean, ~sd), na.rm = TRUE))
```

However with this I am getting below error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Res`.
ℹ `Res = apply(as.matrix(.), 1, ifelse(Function, ~mean, ~sd), na.rm = TRUE)`.
✖ attempt to replicate an object of type 'language'
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Can you please help me on right way to apply condition to chose a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(dplyr)
Function = TRUE
as.data.frame(matrix(1:12, 4)) %>%
  mutate(Res = apply(as.matrix(.), 1, if (Function) mean else sd, na.rm = TRUE))
```

`ifelse` is a function that takes a vector and applies a logical condition to it, and returns a vector containing some specified value if that condition is true for that element, or another specified value if that condition is false for that element. The separate `if` `else` operators are used for conditionals when programming in R. Sometimes they're interchangeable and sometimes they're not.